# Angular 10 Error occurs in the template of component HomeComponent

Tags: angular

hi guys i recently update my angular project to version num 10.0.1
and i face this problem after update [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHZjH.png)

i import FormsModule in app.module.ts
and put it in imports array

any help please?

#### my app.module.ts

i import ngmodule,commonmodule,formsmodule and material module
material module is a custome module that i build it to put all angular material inside it

```
import { MaterialModule } from './../material';
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ProductComponent } from './product/product.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms'
import { CrudService } from './crud.service';
import { ToastrModule } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import { FilterPipeModule } from 'ngx-filter-pipe';
import { FilterPipe } from "./Pipes";
import { MarketsComponent } from './markets/markets.component';
import { CustomFormsModule } from 'ng2-validation';
import { OrdersComponent } from './orders/orders.component'
import { FilterByStatePipe } from './FilterByState.pipe';
import { PointsComponent } from './points/points.component';
import { UsersComponent } from './users/users.component';
import { CatComponent } from './cat/cat.component';
import { OffersComponent } from './offers/offers.component';
import { CitiesComponent } from './cities/cities.component';
import { FAQComponent } from './faq/faq.component';
import { NgxLoadingModule, ngxLoadingAnimationTypes } from 'ngx-loading';
import { NgxUiLoaderModule, NgxUiLoaderHttpModule, NgxUiLoaderRouterModule, NgxUiLoaderConfig } from 'ngx-ui-loader';
import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free';
import { MDBBootstrapModule } from 'angular-bootstrap-md';
import { StatComponent } from './stat/stat.component';
import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts';
import { ChartModule } from 'angular2-chartjs';
import { OrderSearchComponent } from './order-search/order-search.component';
import { CustomLableComponent } from './custom-lable/custom-lable.component';
import { OverlayModule } from '@angular/cdk/overlay';
import { ScrollingModule, ScrollDispatcher } from '@angular/cdk/scrolling';
import { ChatComponent } from './chat/chat.component';
import { DatePipe, CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { CouponComponent } from './coupon/coupon.component';
import { NgxMatDatetimePickerModule, NgxMatTimepickerModule } from '@angular-material-components/datetime-picker';
import {
  MatTooltipModule
} from '@angular/material/tooltip';

const ngxUiLoaderConfig: NgxUiLoaderConfig = {
  bgsColor: "#00a79d",
  bgsOpacity: 0.5,
  bgsPosition: "bottom-right",
  bgsSize: 60,
  bgsType: "ball-spin-clockwise",
  blur: 6,
  delay: 0,
  fgsColor: "#00a79d",
  fgsPosition: "center-center",
  fgsSize: 60,
  fgsType: "ball-spin-clockwise",
  gap: 24,
  logoPosition: "center-center",
  logoSize: 120,
  logoUrl: "",
  masterLoaderId: "master",
  overlayBorderRadius: "0",
  overlayColor: "rgba(40, 40, 40, 0.8)",
  pbColor: "red",
  pbDirection: "ltr",
  pbThickness: 3,
  hasProgressBar: true,
  text: "",
  textColor: "#FFFFFF",
  textPosition: "center-center",
  maxTime: -1,
  minTime: 500
};

export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, 'assets/i18n/', '.json');
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    ProductComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    FilterPipe,
    MarketsComponent,
    OrdersComponent,
    PointsComponent,
    UsersComponent,
    CatComponent,
    OffersComponent,
    CitiesComponent,
    FAQComponent,
    StatComponent,
    OrderSearchComponent,
    CustomLableComponent,
    ChatComponent,
    CouponComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ToastrModule.forRoot(),
    HttpClientModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    }),
    FilterPipeModule,
    CustomFormsModule,
    NgxLoadingModule.forRoot({
      animationType: ngxLoadingAnimationTypes.cubeGrid,
      backdropBackgroundColour: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
      backdropBorderRadius: '4px',
      primaryColour: '#00a79d',
      secondaryColour: '#ffffff',
      tertiaryColour: '#ffffff'
    }),
    NgxUiLoaderModule.forRoot(ngxUiLoaderConfig),
    NgxUiLoaderHttpModule.forRoot({ showForeground: true }),
    NgxUiLoaderRouterModule,
    FontAwesomeModule,
    MDBBootstrapModule.forRoot(),
    ChartsModule,
    ChartModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    ScrollingModule,
    OverlayModule,
    MaterialModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    NgxMatDatetimePickerModule
  ],
  providers: [CookieService, FilterByStatePipe, CrudService, ScrollDispatcher, MaterialModule, DatePipe],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

### material.ts

```
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatTooltipModule } from '@angular/material/tooltip';
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import { MatTabsModule } from '@angular/material/tabs';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material/menu';
import { MatProgressBarModule } from '@angular/material/progress-bar';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatSnackBarModule } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import { MatExpansionModule } from '@angular/material/expansion';
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MatListModule } from '@angular/material/list';
import { MatBadgeModule } from '@angular/material/badge';
import { MatBottomSheetModule } from '@angular/material/bottom-sheet';
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { MatRadioModule } from '@angular/material/radio';
import { MatAutocompleteModule } from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
import { MatTreeModule } from '@angular/material/tree';
import { MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { MatSliderModule } from '@angular/material/slider';
import { LayoutModule } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import { ScrollingModule, ScrollDispatcher } from '@angular/cdk/scrolling'
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { from } from 'rxjs';

@NgModule({
  imports: [MatButtonModule, MatCheckboxModule, MatTabsModule, MatToolbarModule,
    MatIconModule, MatMenuModule, MatProgressBarModule, MatInputModule,
    LayoutModule, MatDialogModule, MatTreeModule, MatListModule, MatTableModule, MatFormFieldModule, MatCardModule, MatBadgeModule, MatSnackBarModule,
    MatExpansionModule, MatBottomSheetModule, ScrollingModule, MatPaginatorModule, MatSelectModule, MatAutocompleteModule, MatRadioModule, MatDatepickerModule
    , MatTooltipModule],

  exports: [MatButtonModule, MatCheckboxModule, MatTabsModule, MatToolbarModule,
    MatIconModule, MatMenuModule, MatProgressBarModule, MatInputModule,
    LayoutModule, MatDialogModule, MatTreeModule, MatListModule, MatTableModule, MatFormFieldModule, MatCardModule, MatBadgeModule, MatSnackBarModule,
    MatExpansionModule, MatBottomSheetModule, ScrollingModule, MatPaginatorModule, MatSelectModule, MatAutocompleteModule, MatRadioModule, MatDatepickerModule
    , MatTooltipModule],
  providers: [
    ScrollDispatcher
  ]
})
export class MaterialModule { }
```

Comment: the errors shown in your screenshot are not related to the FormModule.

Comment: okay, i don't know the cause of the error

Comment: Delete node_modules and package.lock -and run npm install again. Did you upgrade using ng update..?

Comment: yes i update using ng update

Comment: same issue still exist @MikeOne

Answer (score 0):

Your error clearly states that mdb-icon is not defined if its an npm module you are using, add it in imports section of your app module

Comment: i get same error when using ngClass and ngStyle @Navitas28

Comment: error NG8002: Can't bind to 'ngStyle' since it isn't a known property of 'label'.

75                         ```<label [ngStyle]="(dir=='rtl')?{'float':'right'}:{'float':'left'}">{{'TBUserName'|translate}}</label>```

Comment: Can you post your app.module.ts

Comment: For material components like matToolTip you have to import them explicitly like MatToolBarModule just importing the Material Module won't work and then your issue regarding ngStyle it should not come could you first resolve mat tooltip errors and then check

Comment: i edit post and add material.ts  that i add on it all angular material component @Navitas28